# Definition of invariance of right cosets under right multiplication

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, and suppose $g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_r\in G$. Consider the right cosets $Hg_1,Hg_2,\cdots,Hg_r$. What does it mean for the family $\{Hg_i\}_{1\leq i \leq r}$ to be ''invariant under right multiplication by $H$''?

Comment: If you right multiply by a constant $h \in H$ all the resulting cosets are still a partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

It means that for each $g_i$ and each $h\in H$ there exists a $g_j$ (depending on $h$) such that
$$Hg_ih = Hg_j$$
If $H$ is normal, then $g_j=g_i$ because
$$Hg_ih = H(g_ihg_i^{-1})g_i=Hg_i$$
If $H$ is not normal the coset can differ from $Hg_i$.